# Running Selenium WebDriver test in parallel with NUnit3

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, nunit-3.0

I am using Parallelizable Attribute of NUnit3 to run my Selenium WebDriver tests, but test is always running sequential. Number of worker is by default 4 for my machine. I have 2 fixtures like below:

```
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
    public class SeleniumTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void Is_Title_Correct()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.nl");
            string actualTitle = driver.Title;
            string expectedTitle = "Google";
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedTitle, actualTitle, "title is not correct");
            driver.Quit();
        }
   }
```

How can I get it to run in parallel, so that it can open two browsers at once?

Comment: Do you have another TextFixtures or you have all tests under only 1 you shown?

Comment: I have one another test fixture:    `[TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
    public class SeleniumTest2
    {
        [Test]
        public void Is_Title_Correct()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.nl");
            string actualTitle = driver.Title;
            string expectedTitle = "Google";
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedTitle, actualTitle, "title is not correct");
            driver.Quit();
        }
   }`

Comment: Have you tried to run these 2 different TestFixtures together?

Comment: I am running both TestFixtures with Nunit3 Console runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what unit test runner you are using to run your tests. I have the problem without solution yet. But just to give you an idea how to proceed further...

If you are using (1) Visual Studio NUnit Test Adapter - it's obviously not supporting NUnit 3 yet; (2) ReSharper unit test runner only latest version (10) supports NUnit 3 - I would try it first to run unit tests in parallel from VS; (3) NUnit 3 console unit test runner - when I've looked at it, it was not ready to run unit tests in parallel. It might able now, something to look at.

Again, the main idea it to look for a tool which will run your tests in parallel.

Comment: I am using Nunit3 console runner. Tests are running sequential with it.

Comment: I tried running my tests with ReSharper 10, tests are running in parallel now. Thanks!!

Comment: @Megha Please mark the answer as answered. Thank you.
I've also tried NUnit 3 Console - it's not ready yet to run tests in parallel. You can read about this in official documentation: https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Framework-Parallel-Test-Execution

Comment: @Megha how do you use Resharper 10 to run your tests? It doesn't work for me:(

Comment: @DenisKoreyba - Check ReSharper > Options >  Number of assemblies. You can change it to number of processor on your machine. I am able to run tests in parallel with NUnit3 Console runner as well, I just changed web driver to Chrome web driver. I still need to figure out why its not running in parallel with firefox web driver.

Comment: @Megha no I mean my ReSharper 10 can't run my NUnit 3 tests at all. There must be some runner runtime or what? It worked with NUnit 2 but not with NUnit 3 :(

Comment: @DenisKoreyba - Check settings ReSharper > Options> Tools > Unit Testing > NUnit. Mine is using NUnit 3 test runner when nunit.framework 3.x id referenced.

Comment: @Megha thanks a lot! This what you told + some more options helped me!